# What is the correct way to combine transforms together?

Tags: c++, rendering, matrix, transformation, linear-algebra

I have a type called `transform` in my game engine:

```c
struct transform {
    glm::vec3 position;
    glm::vec3 scale;
    glm::quat orientation;

    friend auto matrix(transform const& t) noexcept -> glm::mat4 {
        return
              glm::translate(glm::mat4{1.f}, t.position)
            * glm::toMat4(t.orientation)
            * glm::scale(glm::mat4{1.f}, t.scale);
    }
};
```

It allows to to set position, scaling and orientation separately, retrieve them for many computation and also allows me to get the model matrix using `matrix(my_transform)`.

This is all sound and good, until I tried to combine them.

I have a very simple `model` type that contains many members, including those two:

```c
struct model {
    transform entity_transform; // transform from the entity
    transform origin;           // we apply a different origin to
                                // the entity transform to add offset or scaling
    // ... other members
};

// in a different file
auto draw(model const& m) -> void {
    auto const transformation_matrix = combine(m.entity_transform, m.origin);

    // draw using the transformation matrix
}
```

Technically, there are two ways I can combine those two. First, I can combine them memberwise:

```c
auto combine(transform const& t1, transform const& t2) noexcept -> glm::mat4 {
    return matrix(
        transform{
            .position = t1.position + t2.position,
            .scale = t1.scale * t2.scale,
            .orientation = t1.orientation * t2.orientation
        }
    );
}
```

Or I can combine them by simply convert them to matrices:

```c
auto combine(transform const& t1, transform const& t2) noexcept -> glm::mat4 {
    return matrix(t1) * matrix(t2);
}
```

Are those two combine function equivalent? If not, what would be the correct one? If the two are correct in their own way, which one should I choose?

Comment: If your scale can be non-uniform, then there are combinations that can be expressed by a matrix but not member-wise.

Comment: The two can't be equivalent, because matric multiplication is not commutative, while your operation is.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Hmm, is there a way to make the equivalent of a multiplication but without going back and forth from members to matrix and back to members?

Comment: I think DMGregory is right. This is impossible, because your class doesn't support skew (aka non-orthogonal axes), which is needed when you scale not along the coordinate axes.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yeah! I plan to add skew and perspective to be able to support everything.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat in fact, I added a bounty to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54043989/glmdecompose-and-then-compose-back-again . I would love to do that memberwise to avoid the cost of transforming to matrix and decompose, but I have no idea how to do that yet.

Comment: But if you want all those features, maybe use matrices (4x4) instead of your custom transforms?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I used a transform to be able to get each component and set them before transforming them into matrices. To do that using only a matrix 4x4 I would need to decompose and recompose them everytime I need to retrieve or set one of the component.